# I want to add several lines to a cell of jTable

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I have this code for filling the jTable

```
public void llenarTabla() {               
    DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel(){
    @Override  
        public Class getColumnClass(int col) {
            switch(col) {
                case 0: return ImageIcon.class;
                case 1: return Object.class;
                default: return Object.class;
            }
        }
    };
    tblAnimales.setModel(modelo);
    int i  = 0;
    try {
        //Llenar las cabeceras de la tabla
        modelo.addColumn("Foto");
        modelo.addColumn("Nombre");

        if (cboOrdenar.getSelectedIndex() < 2) {
            if (cboOrdenar2.getSelectedIndex() == 0) {
                rs = animal.consultarEn(cboMostrar.getSelectedItem().toString(), cboOrdenar.getSelectedItem().toString(), "ASC"); 
                //System.out.println(cboMostrar.getSelectedItem().toString() + cboOrdenar.getSelectedItem().toString() + "ASC");
            } else {
                rs = animal.consultarEn(cboMostrar.getSelectedItem().toString(), cboOrdenar.getSelectedItem().toString(), "DESC");
                //System.out.println(cboMostrar.getSelectedItem().toString() + cboOrdenar.getSelectedItem().toString() + "DESC");
            }
        } else if (cboOrdenar.getSelectedIndex() == 2){
            rs = animal.consultarPor(cboMostrar.getSelectedItem().toString(), "size", cboOrdenar2.getSelectedItem().toString());
            //System.out.println(cboMostrar.getSelectedItem().toString() + "size" + cboOrdenar2.getSelectedItem().toString());
        } else {
            rs = animal.consultarPor(cboMostrar.getSelectedItem().toString(), cboOrdenar.getSelectedItem().toString(), cboOrdenar2.getSelectedItem().toString());
            //System.out.println(cboMostrar.getSelectedItem().toString() + cboOrdenar.getSelectedItem().toString() + cboOrdenar2.getSelectedItem().toString());
        }

        while (rs.next()) {
            Blob blob = rs.getBlob("foto");
            byte[] data = blob.getBytes(1, (int)blob.length());
            blob.free();

            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);

            Object [] ob = new Object[2];
            ob[0] = icon;
            ob[1] = rs.getString("idAnimal") + ". " + rs.getString("nombre") + "\n" +
                    "Especie:" + rs.getString("especie") + "\n" +
                    "Raza:" + rs.getString("raza") + "\n" +
                    "Tamaño:" + rs.getString("size") + "\n" +
                    "Edad:" + rs.getString("edad") + " meses\n" +
                    "Características:\n:" + rs.getString("caracteristicas");

            modelo.addRow(ob);
            ob = null;
            tblAnimales.setRowHeight(i, 200);
            i++;
        }
    } catch (SQLException | IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error en MdiHuellitas.llenarTabla()\n" + ex.getMessage());
    }        
}
```

But the case shows the data in just one line, plus I get a Error and the jTable just fills one row when there should be 3. I'm taking the data from mysql, the animal.consultar methods all work ok.

[image]

The line with the first Error is the next:

```
byte[] data = blob.getBytes(1, (int)blob.length());
```

Comment: Is this all the code needed to run the program? Please see: [mcve].

Comment: that's the void that fills the table